# AngularJS Promises?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angular-fullstack to create an app. In my app, I use the Yelp API to get search results, which I want to store in a variable (Note: this.searchTerm is changed via an ng-model in the HTML):

```
'use strict';

(function() {

class MainController {

  constructor($http) {
    this.$http = $http;
    this.awesomeThings = [];
    this.searchTerm = "";
    this.data = [];
  }

  addThing() {
    this.$http.get('/api/messages/city/' + this.searchTerm).success(function(res){
      this.data = res;
    });
  };
}

angular.module('nightlifeApp').controller('MainController', MainController);})();
```

When I do so, I get an error that this.data is not defined. I understand that this is do to the nature of async calls, but how can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: How do you call the `addThing()` method ?

Comment: It is called via an ng-click on a button in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

The `this` keyword is undefined inside a `.then` function in strict mode. Set a local variable to reference the `this` binding inside the `then` function.

```
'use strict';

(function() {

class MainController {

  constructor($http) {
    this.$http = $http;
    this.awesomeThings = [];
    this.searchTerm = "";
    this.data = [];
  }

  addThing() {
    var self = this;
    this.$http.get('/api/messages/city/' + this.searchTerm).then (function(res){
      self.data = res.data;
    });
  };
}

angular.module('nightlifeApp').controller('MainController', MainController);})();
```

Also the `.success` method is **deprecated**. Use `.then` instead.