# angular 2: when resolving promise in component via service 'this' is 'window'

Tags: angular, this, angular-promise, angular2-services

I'm following the quickstart tutorial for Angular 2 (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html#!#review-the-app-structure) and I got stuck in the Services chapter. This is my component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'main',
  templateUrl: 'main/main.template.html',
  styleUrls: ['main/main.component.css'],

  providers: [HeroService],
  directives: [HeroComponent]
})

export class MainComponent implements OnInit {
  title: String = 'Tour of heroes';
  heroes: Hero[];
  selectedHero: Hero;

  constructor(private _heroService: HeroService) {

  }

  getHeroes() {
    this._heroService.getHeroes().then(heroes =>
      this.heroes = heroes
    );
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getHeroes();
  }

  onSelect(hero: Hero) { this.selectedHero = hero; }
}
```

As you can see it implements `OnInit`, which executes the component's `getHeroes` method, which in turns calls the injected `HeroService`:

```
import { Injectable } from 'angular2/core';
import { HEROES } from '../hero/hero.mock';

@Injectable()
export class HeroService {
  public getHeroes() {
    return Promise.resolve(HEROES);
  }

}
```

The promise resolves successfully and I get the array from `hero.mock.ts` in the response variable:

```
getHeroes() {
  this._heroService.getHeroes().then(heroes =>  // heroes = Array[10]
    this.heroes = heroes
  );
}
```

The problem I'm facing is the first `this` (`this._heroService`) is correctly set to `MainComponent`, but the second one (`this.heroes`) is referencing the `Window` javascript object. I've checked several other answers, including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34478112/1983268) and done as they suggest, but the problem remains. Can anyone think of a reason why this is happening?

**Edit:** Generated javascript for MainComponent#getHeroes

```
MainComponent.prototype.getHeroes = function () {
    var _this = this;
    this._heroService.getHeroes().then(function (heroes) {
        return _this.heroes = heroes;
     });
};
MainComponent.prototype.ngOnInit = function () {
    this.getHeroes();
};
```

**Another edit:**
If I change the method calling the service to this (note the curly brackets wrapping everything after the `=>`) then `this` *is* `MainComponent`, but neither the changes in the title nor in the `heroes` array are reflected in the view:

```
getHeroes() {
  this._heroService.getHeroes().then(heroes => {
    console.log(this);
    this.title = 'modified string';
    this.heroes = heroes;
  });
}
```

Comment: What about making a reproducible Plunker by using the Plunker provided in the tutorial and modify it so it demonstrates your issue? (https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/toh-4/ts/plnkr.html)

Comment: How exactly did you figure out that 'this' is 'window'? It is highly unlikely that     `this._heroService.getHeroes().then(heroes => this.heroes = heroes)` will result in different `this` contexts, just because it can't do that with an arrow.

Comment: Could you provide the compiled ES5 code for this TypeScript class? Thanks!

Comment: @estus I just breakpointed it in the chrome devtools and checked the content.

Comment: @Thierry sure! I'll do that in the afternoon.

Comment: @Günter I'll get the plunker done later on, thanks!

Comment: I created a plunkr for your problem: https://plnkr.co/edit/6cja0ICCVjaKRINoRBA0?p=preview. But I can't reproduce it...

Comment: @Thierry I'm creating the plunkr. In the meantime, I pushed to github https://github.com/gatperdut/heroes

Comment: I added the relevant generated js too.

Comment: I've tested your code but I got no exception...

Comment: hey @Hamed no exception is happening, it just fails to render anything. there's an addendum to my question involving curly brackets `{ }` which actually make `this` have the correct value. still, nothing is rendered.

Comment: @Thierry so I managed to make `this` be `MainComponent`, but the changes (updating the `heroes` attribute) don't seem to be reflected. Where are you defining `Hero` in your plnkr, by the way?

Comment: What was your problem? To make your changes reflected, you need to have instantiate your `heroes` array within Angular2. I mean in the constructor of a service or a component...

Comment: yep, the array is instantiated as `heroes: Hero[];` in the component like in the question and the github repo. Thank you anyway, I'll keep hacking at it.

Comment: @CarlosRomero you really should create a plunkr for your code because it seems like many are having problems understanding your issues ...

Comment: I posted somewhere above the github repo. At any rate, I fixed it -- it seemed to be a problem with library versions, since all I changed was the `<script>` tags to reference outside sources (`<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.2/angular2.dev.js"></script>` for example) and...voilà, working as expected. So I kind had it right from the beginning grr